# How to use iCloud calendar without having an Apple device

Tags: icloud, calendar, unix, pc

My boss wants us to use the iCloud calendar app. However, I use a computer with Ubuntu and an Android phone. Because I do not have an Apple device, the calendar app is unavailable to me on icloud.com; only pages, numbers and keynote are available. Would downloading iCloud for Windows via Wine give me iCal, or is there another solution?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If your boss is requiring the use of iCalendar then he/she should also provide you the means to use it!  Have a look at: [List of applications with iCalendar support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_applications_with_iCalendar_support)

Comment: Thanks! It's not required, but it would be very helpful. The team had been using it before I joined. She was unaware that it was unavailable to non-Apple users.

Comment: iCalendar is not Apple technology and you do not necessarily need Apple per se in any way to use iCalendar even thought Apple makes use of it.  You might want to read what [iCalendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) actually is on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! My mistake for assuming the calender app would be called iCalendar. I mean the calender app on icloud.com. As far as I can tell, unless I have an apple device, I cannot use the calender app available to those with at least one Apple device.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't add iCloud Calendar support to an Apple ID without turning it on via an iOS or Mac device.

You can borrow someone's Apple device and turn it on for the Apple ID in Settings > iCloud, on an iOS device or System Preferences > iCloud, on a Mac.

Once you have turned on "Calendars" for the device, you can immediately disable it and sign out of your boss' Apple ID, and your boss should be able to access iCloud Calendar from [www.icloud.com](http://www.icloud.com).